# Limits of indefinite Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

My professor went through this very quickly and I didn't quite understood. This appeared on exercises without any context and my textbook/class notes do not talk about these limits - but I know it is related to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and L'Hopital rule.

How does one solve this?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)dt}{t}-x}{x^3}$$

My guess is: I should integrate in terms of $t$ to get $F(x) - F(0)$. Then I should use L'Hopital rule in order to solve the limit. Is this right?

If so: what does it mean geometrically? What if I had a function  (ex. $x^2$ on the boundaries of the integral - should I use the composition of functions? And what if the function is undefined there? In this case we have it on $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The idea is to show that as $x \to \infty$, the numerator diverges, hence, when you look at the limit of the whole fraction, L'Hospital's rule applies. To take the derivative of the numerator, you will need the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, i.e.
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[\int_a^{x} f(t) dt \right] = f(x).
$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Can I use the fact that $\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)dt}{t} = 0$ when $x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @rato does not look relevant now - you need $x\to \infty$, not $x \to 0$